# How to install Redux after creating a React application using create-react-app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Created an application using create-react-app. I wrote just the word **test** in the render method to display on the screen. And everything is ok.

Then I write: `npm install --save redux` for the folder with the application and the application does not work.

In console error:
[image]

How then to install redux after create-react-app? What is the procedure step by step?
Or Maybe you know some article where they describe step by step? Or do you know some video on YouTube?

Comment: please check may be you are importing redx instead of redux in your react app.

Comment: This is a known issue and has to do with incompatible versions. Check here for solutions: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7183

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you installed redux you might have mispelled it while installing because in your screenshot see the error carefully it is shown the redux spelling as 'redx' so try fixing it by installing correctly with npm or try with yarn.

To do with npm :-

```
npm i redux --save
```

And if you want to install any packages with yarn you can do so with following command :-

```
yarn add redux
```

The other thing I have seen in your image is that there is an error of @babel/runtime if the error is coming again after installing redux correctly then you might have to install it manually.

First you need to remove the node_modules completely and then install the @babel/runtime package

To do with npm :-

```
npm i @babel/runtime --save OR npm add @babel/runtime
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it might be late but I have written a Step-by-Step guide on "How to Add Redux into create-react-app".

You can find the link of the blog here.

https://www.realmelon.com/react-redux-how-to-add-redux-into-create-react-app/

Moreover, I have uploaded the Video for the same.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IfRk6mdIb90&t=31s

If you still find any issues in installing "Redux on React", please let me know

Happy Learning